# ValueError: Variable A3C_net/basic_lstm_cell/weights does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable()

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

When I contruct a LSTM with tf.nn.dynamic_rnn, the problem about name_scope lead to its fail and the platform is WINDOWS 10. I can not resolve it and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks very much!

The whole err is as following:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "a3c_prediction.py", line 157, in <module>
    main()
  File "a3c_prediction.py", line 88, in main
    global_network = ACLSTMNetwork(ACTION_SIZE, device)
  File "C:\Users\xjZhan\Desktop\a3c_predication\a3c_net_lstm.py", line 139, in __init__
    scope = scope)
  File "C:\Program Install\Anaconda3-4.1.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py", line 553, in dynamic_rnn
    dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Program Install\Anaconda3-4.1.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py", line 720, in _dynamic_rnn_loop
    swap_memory=swap_memory)
  File "C:\Program Install\Anaconda3-4.1.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2623, in while_loop
    result = context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "C:\Program Install\Anaconda3-4.1.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2456, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "C:\Program Install\Anaconda3-4.1.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2406, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "C:\Program Install\Anaconda3-4.1.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py", line 703, in _time_step
    skip_conditionals=True)
  File "C:\Program Install\Anaconda3-4.1.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py", line 177, in _rnn_step
    new_output, new_state = call_cell()
  File "C:\Program Install\Anaconda3-4.1.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py", line 691, in <lambda>
    call_cell = lambda: cell(input_t, state)
  File "C:\Program Install\Anaconda3-4.1.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\rnn\python\ops\core_rnn_cell_impl.py", line 241, in __call__
    concat = _linear([inputs, h], 4 * self._num_units, True)
  File "C:\Program Install\Anaconda3-4.1.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\rnn\python\ops\core_rnn_cell_impl.py", line 1044, in _linear
    _WEIGHTS_VARIABLE_NAME, [total_arg_size, output_size], dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Program Install\Anaconda3-4.1.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 1049, in get_variable
    use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "C:\Program Install\Anaconda3-4.1.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 948, in get_variable
    use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "C:\Program Install\Anaconda3-4.1.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 356, in get_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape, use_resource=use_resource)
  File "C:\Program Install\Anaconda3-4.1.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 341, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource)
  File "C:\Program Install\Anaconda3-4.1.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 671, in _get_single_variable
    "VarScope?" % name)
```

**ValueError: Variable A3C_net/basic_lstm_cell/weights does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?**

---

```
scope_name = "A3C_net"
with tf.device(self._device),tf.variable_scope(scope_name) as scope:
    self.W_conv1, self.b_conv1 = self._conv_variable([8, 8, 4, 16])
    self.W_conv2, self.b_conv2 = self._conv_variable([4, 4, 16, 32])

    self.W_fc1, self.b_fc1 = self._fc_variable([2592, 256])
    # lstm
    self.lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(256, state_is_tuple=True, reuse=True)#
    # weight for policy output layer
    self.W_fc2, self.b_fc2 = self._fc_variable([256, action_size])
    # weight for value output layer
    self.W_fc3, self.b_fc3 = self._fc_variable([256, 1])

    self.s = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 84, 84, 4])

    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(self._conv2d(self.s,  self.W_conv1, 4) + self.b_conv1)
    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(self._conv2d(h_conv1, self.W_conv2, 2) + self.b_conv2)
    h_conv2_flat = tf.reshape(h_conv2, [-1, 2592])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_conv2_flat, self.W_fc1) + self.b_fc1)
    h_fc1_reshaped = tf.reshape(h_fc1, [1,-1,256])  # batches steps inputs

    self.step_size = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1])
    self.initial_lstm_state0 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 256])
    self.initial_lstm_state1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 256])
    self.initial_lstm_state = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(
                                      self.initial_lstm_state0,
                                      self.initial_lstm_state1)
    lstm_outputs, self.lstm_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(self.lstm,
    h_fc1_reshaped,initial_state = self.initial_lstm_state,dtype= tf.float32,
                                     sequence_length = self.step_size,
                                     time_major = False,
                                     scope = scope)

    lstm_outputs = tf.reshape(lstm_outputs, [-1,256])

    # policy (output)
    self.pi = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(lstm_outputs, self.W_fc2) + self.b_fc2)
    # value (output)
    v_ = tf.matmul(lstm_outputs, self.W_fc3) + self.b_fc3
    self.v = tf.reshape( v_, [-1] )

    scope.reuse_variables()
    self.W_lstm = tf.get_variabl("basic_lstm_cell/weights")                  
    self.b_lstm = tf.get_variable("basic_lstm_cell/biases")
    self.reset_state()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it very sample and as following: replace tf.get_variabl with tf.Variabl